# Dog Agility Tracker- Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA using increasing range of cells, absolute reference and referencing a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've been working on a spreadsheet the last few days to track my dogs' agility runs, titles and points.  I'm not very spreadsheet savvy but can muck my way around to get the desired result most of the time.  If this spreadsheet was just for myself, I'd be happy with just entering the various titles as they are earned.  However, I'd like to share this with my fellow agility friends and classmates, so they can better track their own dogs' accomplishments, especially for those just starting out.  To that end, I want it set up to automatically fill in the titles.

The biggest challenge I had was figuring out the right formula that would tally the correct number of qualifying runs (Qs) and points (if needed) to earn a specific title and then making sure that title wasn't repeated.  On a separate sheet, I created a formula for each title that would give a TRUE/FALSE value.  Then I created a formula that would return the earned title if there was a MATCH for the TRUE value.  I was pretty pleased with myself until I realized how messy it was to copy all of formulas down and how quickly it would bloat my spreadsheet.

It seems that an `ARRAYFORMULA` would best suit my needs but I cannot figure out how make it work for my formulas.  I had hoped it would be as easy as just using `ARRAYFORMULA()` but that didn't copy it down, probably because the [Column][Row]:[Column] wasn't defined?:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND((countifs(Lexi!G$17:G19,"STD- Novice A",Lexi!H$17:H19, "✔") + countifs(Lexi!G$17:G19,"STD- Novice B",Lexi!H$17:H19,"✔"))=3,COUNTIF(Lexi!I$17:Lexi!I18,'Lexi-Titles'!B$18)=0))
```

I then tried using an IF statement that did define the array range but that didn't work correctly either.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Lexi!G19:G<>"",AND((countifs(Lexi!G$17:G19,"STD- Novice A",Lexi!H$17:H19, "✔") + countifs(Lexi!G$17:G19,"STD- Novice B",Lexi!H$17:H19,"✔"))=3,COUNTIF(Lexi!I$17:Lexi!I18,'Lexi-Titles'!B$18)=0),"")
```

I've also tried defining all the cells to meet the array parameters (at least I thought so):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND((countifs((Lexi!G$17):(Lexi!G19:G),"STD- Novice A",(Lexi!H$17):(Lexi!H19:H), "✔") + countifs(Lexi!G$17):(Lexi!G19:G),"STD- Novice B",(Lexi!H$17):(Lexi!H19:H),"✔"))=3,COUNTIF((Lexi!I$17):(Lexi!I18:I),'Lexi-Titles'!B$18)=0))
```

I'm likely doing something wrong or perhaps `ARRAYFORMULA` won't work for my situation and the real solution is beyond my understanding?

I'm too new to embed photos so [here's a link to my Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mVoBc4oqQ6F9Wd3ZHAIqDE5YFIeWsRbD-1VUZ2CMCb4/edit?usp=sharing) instead

On the Lexi and Lexi-Title sheets, I have highlighted the cells in cyan that need to be copied down.

It's my actual sheet, not a duplicate, so I have it set to "View Only" to prevent my friends from accidentally changing something.  Should dog agility videos interest you, that's fine!  Thank you for any help or advice you can offer.

Comment: "Dog agility". At last, something I can get my teeth into (ahem).

Comment: Welcome. I've spent some time looking at your spreadsheet. FWIW I think I would have taken a different approach to the design of the "titles" sheet. Normally, I would expect that it would describe the various parameters required for each title (all 171 of them), so that a formula on, say, "Lexi" could evaluate a result. Did you entertain this approach at any stage?

Comment: I don't know about dog's agility but there are a crazy amount of titles. And the formula changes for every row, could you maybe explain your thought on how this titles sheets needs to work? What do the row represents? The columns are the title but I don't understand why there are so many rows too.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at it.  Defining the titles was what I'd initially thought I'd do but then wasn't sure how to go about it.  I'd considered VLOOKUP where the title would be in the first lookup column, second column would be the title requirements resulting in TRUE/FALSE but then how would I define the "when" so the titles are filled into the earning run and never duplicated?  I don't think UNIQUE or QUERY would work.  Truly, I'm not very experienced with spreadsheets, certainly more today than last week...  (I am reworking some titles using FLOOR & CONCAT which helps a bit)

Comment: There should be a row for every run (though I just copied the formula down a tone of rows in lieu of getting ARRAYFORMULA to work).  Doing an INDEX/MATCH of the row corresponding to each run insures only one title is earned for that run and that it's never duplicated.  It was the only way I could figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: I mentioned earlier that I would have taken a different approach to managing the titles and the "Q" and "Title Earned" calculations. I feel that "Lexi-Titles" is flawed, and the data should be normalised. [This sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EEdog2MNRRDEyuQO713ZFChcFRhhefgTq4P6PQTnXqg/edit?usp=sharing) is an example of how I would approach the management of the Title information, and the calculation of dog performances. It is not perfect, but it demonstrates a different approach that may enable you to foresee a workable alternative.